# Lampp Apache cant connect wih PostgreSql server

Tags: lamp, postgresql, mongodb

Basicly i want to Lampp's Apache web server as main webserver for 3 Databases type that i have mysql (bundling with Lampp default),PostgreSql-10 (fully installed and tested),MongoDb (not yet started to install).
i have a problem with the postgre DB that wont connect with my web in xampp apache htdocs 
i run a test in a test folder index.php for testing connection like this..

```
$connection = pg_connect ("host=localhost dbname=survey user=postgres password=linux101114");
if($connection) {
   echo 'connected';
} else {
    echo 'there has been an error connecting';
}
```

but when i run it return just a blank page..
any suggestion for me i need a web server like apache that can run multiple web with 3 type database connection.. (pgsql,mysql,monggo)

Comment: What happens if you run `php index.php` locally?

Comment: i new to ubuntu so..im formerly windows user..im a web programmer..usualy i put my projects on xampp>htdocs.. now  i put my project on opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs.. projects that use mysql database is work fine but not the postgreSQl one..that wont connect to the pgsql database..lampp already configured correctly like windows xampp..

Comment: that the problem i dont know where to put the php index.php if i want to test localy..

Comment: `cd` to the directory where this page `index.php` is stored, and enter `php index.php`.

Comment: but when i open from browser its still return nothing,,i test with localhost and 127.0.0.1